# How to add lightmap to three js?

Tags: three.js, blender

I baked some lightmap from on blender 2.8(Bake type - combined, Influence - "Direct", "Indirect", "Diffuse").
After that, I tried to add lightmap to part of my model.
[image: Lightmap image]

```
    function initColor(parent, type, mtl) {
        parent.traverse(o => {
            if (o.isMesh) {
                if (o.name.includes(type)) {
                    o.material = mtl;
                }
            }
        });
    }
       var lightmapTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/FrontLightmap.png" );
        var front_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({lightMap: lightmapTexture });
          const INITIAL_MAP = [
                {childID: "Front", mtl: front_material}
            ];
       for (let object of INITIAL_MAP) {
           initColor(theModel, object.childID, object.mtl);
       }
```

But the result - black material(front part). 
[image: Black material]

Is there is possible to separately usage of lightmap and different material colors at the same time?
[image: Bad lightmap]

Comment: The docs specify that lightmaps [require a second set of uvs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshLambertMaterial.lightMap). How to add a second set of UVs [is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163765/i-cant-get-the-aomap-showing-in-three-js-using-a-glb-gltf-asset/61195068#61195068)

Comment: @Marquizzo yes, that works. But after I load the texture - It looks bad. (added screenshot) to answer

Comment: @Marquizzo that not a problem with UV - because when I load model with already baked textures - it loads correctly.